# visualstudio.com TFS How to add user without access to code

Tags: tfs

We use visualstudio.com hosted TFS service.
I need to add a QA / tester to our TFS account, but I do not want them to have any access to our code. Simply just access to the GUI to report bugs, nothing more.

Any tips? Right now I believe when I add the user to the project, they can access our code.

Answer (score 1):

You can secure the "Code" separately from the Work Items by going to the "Code" tab and selecting the dropdown next to the project name and selecting Security.